# Why is the C++ standard library divided into several components/libraries?

Tags: c++, standards

The C++ standard divides the standard library into [different distinct components/libraries](https://eel.is/c++draft/library.general#3). Some components are built up of several headers.

Why is the standard organized in this way? What practical advantage does this bring us? Why doesn't the standard library only define headers (+ potentially implementations)?

I am assuming that this information can even be somewhat important to a C++ Dev instead of a committee member/compiler vendor, as cppreference for example often specifies from which library a given header comes from:

> This header is part of the general utility library.

[See here for example.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/expected) Is this assumption true? If yes, when?

Comment: As opposed to lumping everything into a single bucket like PHP does? Even C breaks these out into separate header files.

Comment: It's the same reason novels are divided into chapters, instead of a single contigous blob of text, without any kind of organization, whatsoever.

Comment: @tadman If you define that some things have to go to header A and others to header B, then you don't have this lumping issue either.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. C++ is quite well organized, considering, and a lot of thought has been put into [*separation of concerns*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). Although C++ doesn't steer as heavily into [design patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns) as some other languages do, it does try and adhere to an organizational philosophy that has evolved as the Standard Library itself has.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik A technical specification is no novel though. One has the organization already when defining what goes to what header.

Comment: *'If you define that some things have to go to header A and others to header B'* -- Did you click on any links in that draft? It clearly tells you which headers belongs to which library, and you can further look at the synopsis of each headers to see what exactly each headers need to have.

Comment: @Ranoiaetep I am afraid you might be missing my point here. My question is why we group these headers into libraries. Separation of concerns, organization, etc. is already achieved with the definitions of the headers.

Comment: @Brotcrunsher There are no different libraries in the sense of e.g. `.so`/`.dll` files. The standard specifies only which headers contain which declarations (at a minimum). It doesn't specify anything about the organization of the definitions. There usually is only one library in the sense of one `.so`/`.dll`. But there can also be many or none (they could be compiler-internal). The use of the word "library" is just for organizational purposes inside the standard.

Comment: @user17732522 I get that. My question is why this organization is required, if the headers already give us a form of organization.

Comment: @Brotcrunsher So you want to have a section per header file in the standard instead of the current "library" sections?

Comment: @user17732522 I am not proposing any change to the standard. I just want to understand why this (to me currently seemingly arbitrary) grouping was done. What advantage do we have from it? e.g., does the standard reference any library except for the definition of itself or the enumeration of all libraries? And why does cppreference and other sites even mention the library?

Comment: @Brotcrunsher: "*My question is why this organization is required*" "Required" by whom?

Comment: @NicolBolas Well, if the standard itself defines it, then I imagine it has to serve some purpose. What purpose is this? That we don't already have by defining the headers.

Comment: *'seemingly arbitrary grouping'* -- If you are just looking at the general utility library, then it will look arbitrary, which is why it is called **general**. Most other libraries have a much clearer theme

Comment: @Brotcrunsher: What do you mean by "defines it"? Nothing is defined as far as the behavior of C++ is concerned. You're talking about the name of chapters in the standard. It doesn't have any inherent meaning other than what the words say that they mean.

Comment: This is pretty much purely for the purpose of organizing the standard document in a readable manner. You may find some discussion of particular choices in editorial issues, such as https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/issues/5124.

Comment: The purpose of it is the same as why any manuals would divide different parts into sections. Say it's a car manual, each individual car parts have their distinct purpose, and you can simply have each section dedicated to a specific part without grouping them together. However, we group each dash lights into the same section, so it is easier for the reader to find the information without knowing the exact information they are looking for.

Comment: Most applications do not require the entire library, so including it would be a lot of compile time wasted. Especially on slow machines.

Comment: @NicolBolas That's a good point. I guess I am mainly confused why this information is present on cppreference. This has always felt like noise to me, I don't see whom it helps.

Comment: You also have the headers listed in alphabetical order http://eel.is/c++draft/headers No specific meaning there either.

Comment: Similarly, by grouping different headers into a single library, it gives the readers a quick way to acknowledge what is available. When a people from a different background see `<list>`, it might be hard for them to imagine there were also `<array>` and `<vector>`. By grouping them together, you can easily find all the different containers that is available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Separation of concerns, organization, etc. is already achieved with the definitions of the headers.

Are they?

Consider [Chapter 22: Utilities](https://eel.is/c++draft/utilities). This chapter covers material defined in 13 separate headers. The standard could have had 13 separate chapters, but like... why? What good is that? Is there some reason advantage to putting all of these in separate chapters, when they'd be much shorter than most other chapters?

Consider [Chapter 31: Input/Output](https://eel.is/c++draft/input.output). This chapter covers stuff defined in 14 separate headers. But the stuff in those headers are often highly related to one another. All of the streams are ultimately built on the iostream base classes. Some of them reference things in other headers, like the ability for file streams to use `filesystem::path` objects.

But they're all ultimately stuff about input/output. So it makes sense to bundle them all into one chapter.

They could have had 14 separate chapters, one for each header, but there would be no benefit to that. Indeed, you would now have no place to put the [Iostreams requirements section](https://eel.is/c++draft/iostreams.requirements), which is not bound to *any* header at all.

Speaking of important information that isn't bound to a header, one of the most important sections in the Container chapter is the [Requirements](https://eel.is/c++draft/containers#container.requirements) section, which applies to *every* container. This section is absolutely vital for understanding anything that's happening in any of the container documentation, and in many cases defines the behavior of several functions whose definitions aren't listed in the section for those individual headers. This is because those functions behave the same way for all containers.

I mean, do we *really* need to see *nine separate* repetitions the definitions for `begin`, `end`, etc? The whole point of the containers is to have a uniform interface so that you can understand how stuff works easily. And if you're going to have a uniform interface, repeating the definition of that interface is rather pointless.

And then there are places where the standard can just point directly to a chapter and says, "all that stuff also has this property." The most important being the concept of freestanding implementations. Freestanding implementations are C++ implementations that don't want to implement the entire standard library because it has a lot of stuff their customers don't really need (microcontrollers don't care about filesystems, for examples). But there are parts of the standard library that must be implemented even by those systems.

This was more prominent in pre-C++23 standards, but in many cases, the standard would just say "[everything in this chapter/section must be in freestanding](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/compliance)". That's a lot easier to do when a chapter/section can contain as many headers as it makes sense to.

This is probably part of the reason why the Atomic chapter is *not* part of the Threading chapter (again, pre-C++23).

The organization is purely for human purposes. It has no bearing on how implementations are written, outside of the freestanding stuff.